# Average range only if another range is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am wondering how to write a formula that will do the following.

Average A1 and B1, if A1 is not blank.
If it is blank, average E1 and B1.
If it is also blank, average K1 and B1.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a nested IF:

```
=(IF(A1<>"",A1,IF(E1<>"",E1,K1))+B1)/2
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!